# How to change font color in HTML?

Tags: html

I want to change a paragraph of text to another font color. I have code like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p> Va', pensiero, sull'ali dorate.
       Va', ti posa sui clivi, sui coll,
       ove olezzano tepide e molli
       l'aure dolci del suolo natal!

       Del Giordano le rive saluta,
       di Sionne le torri atterrate.
       O mia Patria, sì bella e perduta!
       O membranza sì cara e fatal!...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i make it appear in other colors?

Comment: Either use CSS or the `style` attribute of the `<p>` tag, and set the `color` CSS attribute to the hex-code or name of the color you need. [Here's](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp) a halfway-decent tutorial.

Comment: don't use the style attribute unless you absolutely can't avoid it, use a css class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go several ways of doing this. You can devine your color by predefined colors (see e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp) or by define the color yourself by hex code (see e.g. http://html-color-codes.info/webfarben_hexcodes/).

## Inline CSS

```
<p style="color:blue">Blue inline CSS font</p>
```

## Internal CSS

Define a style element in your head seaction and all your specified elements will be formatted.

```
<style>
    p {
        color: blue;
    }
</style>

<p>Blue!</p>
```

## External CSS

Same way as internal CSS except you link a CSS file instead of define the sytle in your head section.

This is the common way of styling with CSS, because the file is cached by the browser, so page load time is can be reduced.
To link you could load a CSS file e.g. by

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

## Old depricated way

```
<font color="blue">Blue font</font>
```

or

```
<font color="#1B29A3">Selfdefined blue text</font>
```

Comment: External CSS is the common way, but i think you can go on with inline css for your example

Comment: External CSS is best practice because it is cached by the browser whereas inline CSS is not and causes increased page load times. And I'd say never use the old way.

Comment: answering with the best option first is a better way round to do it - many people will look there first and it's better to send them off doing things right (if only for our sake when we have to work with them). Omitting something as depreciated as the `<font>` tag would also make a better answer I think